# Properties.Settings not working in VS 2013 CE

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013 Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02558

I created a Windows Application project from scratch and added a user setting :

[image: snapshot]

then I tried to use it in program.Main :

```
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    //Application.Run(new Form1());
    string path = Properties.Settings.Default.Path;
}
```

the compiler complains :

```
Error   1   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings' does not contain a definition for 'Path' 
and no extension method 'Path' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    
I:\Dev\Visual Studio 2013\ThrowAway\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs    17  55  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

I checked some old projects and found the same problem.
How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column of the Settings table defines the name of the property, so according to your current settings, the code should be

```
string path = Properties.Settings.Default.Settings;
```

which is probably not what you really want. I guess you wanted to call the setting `Path`, so you should path put "Path" into the first column, called "Name".

Comment: You are absolutely right.  How could I be so silly <blush>.